# Getting the PID of foreground window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing an app that does actions depending on the current context. My goal is to get the path for the EXE that's currently running in the foreground. For this to work, I need to get the process handle for the foreground window. The problem is, with `GetForegroundWindow()` I get back a window handle, and for `OpenProcess()` to work I need to pass in a process ID, not a window handle. Any suggestions?

The code I'm currently using:

```cpp
SetPrivilege(); //setting SE_DEBUG_NAME privilige for getting process path
DWORD processId = GetProcessId(GetForegroundWindow());
std::cout << "PID: " << processId << '\n'; //for debug
std::string ret;
HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(
    PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,
    FALSE,
    processId
);
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: @stark It isn't, anymore.

Comment: Are you ignoring [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) out of intent or ignorance?

Comment: The first reply solved it for me, was a simple fix, don't know how I didn't think of that. And to answer IInspectable 's question, out of intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid):

```
HWND hWnd = GetForegroundWindow ();
DWORD process_id;
GetWindowThreadProcessId (hWnd, &process_id);
```

It's not immediately obvious how this function reports error conditions.

Comment: The documentation doesnt say, but the only possible way it can report an error is by returning 0 for the thread ID, which your example is ignoring

Comment: @RemyLebeau That would seem reasonable, yes.